# Can't use array prototype .find in React stateless component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

My app is rendering this component:

```
<LabelTop orderNumber={order.id} shippingMethodName={getShippingMethod(order.shipping_lines)} customerName={order.billing.first_name + " " + order.billing.last_name}/>
```

`getShippingMethod()` is a simple formatter in the same file.

```
const getShippingMethod = (shipping_lines) => {
  const metaObj = shipping_lines.find(meta => meta.method_title !== "")
  return metaObj.method_title
}
```

If I refactor to move `getShippingMethod()` to the component itself I get the error that `.find` is not a method.

```
export const LabelTop = props => {

const getShippingMethod = (shipping_lines) => {
  const metaObj = shipping_lines.find(meta => meta.method_title !== "")
  return metaObj.method_title
}

return (
  <div>
    <div>
      <img src={LogoIcon} alt="Logo"/>
      <div>{props.orderNumber}</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div><span>Method:</span> {getShippingMethod(props.shippingMethodName)}</div>
      <div><span>Customer:</span> {props.customerName}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
)
}
```

Why?

Comment: Has shipping_lines the same type in the 2 solutions?

Comment: @gkatai yes. I'm just passing down the shipping_lines object array as a prop. Then I try format it to get the right item in the component.

Comment: Isn't it `props.shipping_lines` rather than `props.shippingMethodName` ? Or, let us know what is shippingMethodName?

Comment: @gkatai also if I edit the formatter to just return something like: shipping_lines[0].method_title it works.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing the right arguments to the function. You should pass `props.shipping_lines` to the method

```
export const LabelTop = props => {

    const getShippingMethod = (shipping_lines) => {
      const metaObj = shipping_lines.find(meta => meta.method_title !== "")
      return metaObj.method_title
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <img src={LogoIcon} alt="Logo"/>
          <div>{props.orderNumber}</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div><span>Method:</span> {getShippingMethod(props.shipping_lines)}</div>
          <div><span>Customer:</span> {props.customerName}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )

}
```

However, its better to write the method outside of the `Functional component` because otherwise a new instance of the function will be created on every render of the `LabelTop` component

**EDIT:** It may so happen that the component is not getting the props in the right format. As mentioned in the comments, multiple instances of the component are being rendered and all the instances are not getting the prop as an array and hence it would give an error.

Comment: When I'm calling the component declaring props: `shippingMethodName={order.shipping_lines}`

In the component when I'm using the prop I'm calling the formatter method with: `{getShippingMethod(props.shippingMethodName)}`

Looks right?

Comment: could you show, how you are rendering LabelTop component

Comment: if I edit the formatter to just return the argument with something like: `shipping_lines[0].method_title` it works.

Comment: See first line of question for LabelTop render. Obviously when reformatted it's without the formatter call. So: `<LabelTop orderNumber={order.id} shippingMethodName={order.shipping_lines} customerName={order.billing.first_name + " " + order.billing.last_name}  />`

Comment: can you try logging shipping_lines in the method and see if it outputs an array or an object

Comment: I made a mistake. :( When I logged typeof shipping_lines in the formatter it alternated string and object and I realised I was using the component twice and hadn't refactored the second instance. :( Guess I'll delete the question. Thanks for your help. Or if you edit your answer to suggest that I will mark as accepted answer.